# Are nhibernate entities part of the BL?

Tags: nhibernate

I am looking for the right n-tier modal to adapt to my new nhibernate project. I am quite new to it. I currently have several entities and their corrosponding mapping classes. I can't seem to figure if the entities should act as the BL level classes, or merly an object oriented part of my DAL.

Can anyone help shed light on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I've accepted more or less 50%.

Comment: which is just about the amount of good answers I've recieved. Answers answered but not completely recieved a good rating.

Comment: How about improving your questions?

Comment: cannot improve questions I've already asked. My skills as a programmer are improving over time. I believe my questions are too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entities are defenetly are part of BL layer. They should reflect business meaning. For example if you are writing online shop you will have `User` entity and it will have list of `Order` entities and so on.

You can have a look at different examples and best practices of NHibernate usage, such as 
[Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) and [Nhibernate best practices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx) they all are putting entities in the business layer while their mappings are in data access.